# How do I update JAVA_HOME / JRE_HOME on Tomcat on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat8

I'm trying to set my JRE_HOME variable in catalina.bat to be where my java is stored (/usr/lib/jvm/default-java) in Ubuntu.  I edited catalina.bat and added "set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java" at the very top of the file but when I use "./catalina.sh version" it keeps stating "Using JRE_HOME: /usr".  ***How do I setup my catalina.bat file so that the JRE_HOME will update?***

I've tried a few older guides for older versions of Ubuntu but nothing has worked.  Any and all help is appreciated I just want to get my computer working for java server side programming.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with tomcat, but it sounds like you are editing a Windows specific file `catalina.bat` when you want to be editing `catalina.sh`. Perhaps add a line like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm` to `catalina.sh`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much.  You're right I didn't realize I was editing the Windows version of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you starting tomcat using catalina.bat, it searching for file setenv.bat and sourcing it. It is searching in CATALINA_HOME or CATALINA_BASE

So the better way to set JAVA_HOME for the tomcat is:

Create setenv.bat script CATALINA_BASE/bin, if it is not exists already.
Add this line to setenv.bat

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

Make it executable.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!
One adjustment I had to make is to make it a setenv.sh instead of setenv.bat. I had to adjust the filepath of course as well. Your advice worked though and now it works.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that you are working on Ubuntu. When you say "I edited catalina.bat"

Comment: Yeah another commentor pointed that out to me.  I bought a book that is intended primarily for Windows users so I was editing the completely wrong file.  Thankfully with skyler's comment and yours I was able to get it to work.